will remain...after he argued?
I was reading a news article and found this sentence.

Combs will remain in federal custody after his legal team argued for his release on a $50 million bond in court on Wednesday.

Is it grammatically correct to say "will remain...after his legal team argued"? I think present sense usually comes after "after" in this kind of sentence.
https://www.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/celebrities/2024/09/19/diddy-jail-metropolitan-detention-center-r-kelly/75288259007/

This is newspaper-ese, which is often quite different from normal writing. Here "after" is not being used in a temporal sense, but simply to link the two phrases.


Combs will remain in federal custody after his legal team argued ...

The argument by Comb's legal team was made prior to the above statement, and hence argued was used.
At the time of the statement, the situation didn't change, hence will remain is fine.

Diddy denied bail: Judge rules he will remain in jail until trial


Thank you. Is this way of writing applicable to normal writing or only applicable to news article, as Daniel said?

@Jiro F, The connecting word after does only the connection.  I won't say it's wrong.  To express the contrast, we could use other connecting words: Combs will remain in federal custody although his legal team argued... Combs will remain in federal custody despite his legal team arguing ...
